# PHP database edit, values don't change when submitted

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm trying to add an 'edit' button on my database table output, it captures the information correctly from the previous screen, however when I press the 'update' button, the values just revert back to what they came in as, and nothing is updated on the database. Does anyone have any idea what could be the matter?

```html
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('connect.php');

if ($_SESSION['role']!='Admin') {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

if(isset($_GET['edit_id'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id =".$_GET['edit_id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

}

if(isset($_POST['btn-update'])){
    $productID = $_POST['productID'];
    $productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $productDesc = $_POST['productDesc'];
    $productType = $_POST['productType'];
    $productPrice = $_POST['productPrice'];
    $stockAmount = $_POST['stockAmount'];
    $update = "UPDATE products SET product_id='$productID', name='$productName', description='$productDesc', type='$productType', price='$productPrice', stock_amount='$stockAmount' WHERE product_id=". $_GET['edit_id'];
    $up = mysqli_query($connection, $update);
    if(!isset($sql)){
        die("$sql Error" .mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
        header("location: manage-products.php");
    }
} ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post">
    <h1>Edit Product Information:</h1>
    Product ID:<br>
    <input type="number" name="productID" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>"><br>
    Product Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="productName" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"><br>
    Product Description:<br>
    <input type="text" name="productDesc" value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"><br>
    Product Type:<br>
    <input type="radio" name="productType" value="book" checked> Book<br>
    <input type="radio" name="productType" value="stationary"> Stationary<br>
    <input type="radio" name="productType" value="gift"> Gift<br>
    Product Price:<br>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="any" name="productPrice" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>"><br>
    Stock Amount:<br>
    <input type="number" name="stockAmount" value="<?php echo $row['stock_amount']; ?>"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" name=btn-update" id="btn-update" <strong>Update</strong></button>
    <a href="manage-products.php"><button type="button" value="button">Cancel</button></a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to save $_GET['edit_id'] to a SESSION to save it when POST form. That var do not keep after you press update button.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.